# Laravel - how to filter dropdown with blank value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I hava a dropdown color field. In my table, there is empty value for color but the problem is when I filter other color value it will show the list of table correctly but when I filter the blank value, the table return no records. Is there any way to solve this?
[image]

Here my code so far

Eloquent

```
public function getColor($item_id, $color){

   $query = Color::where('item_id', '=', $item_id)
               ->orWhere('color','=',$color)
               ->paginate(10);
   return $query
}
```

Controller

```
if ($request->item_id || $request->color){
      $filter = $eloquentRepo->getColor($request->item_id, $request->color);
}
else{
     $filter = $eloquentRepo->all();
}
```

Comment: you can add a condition on your eloquent function to check if color field is null and query using whereNull() method
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenull

Comment: This question is very confusing, at least for me. Can you perhaps show what you expect when you select a valid colour and when you select the blank colour?

Comment: @archvayu i did add orWhereNull('color') it still return nothing.

Comment: @user3532758 basically if I select the blank dropdown, the table will only show item id value 2,5,6 as the color column is blank

Comment: Did you add the condition when you tried with orWhereNull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @archvayu mentioned, try with condition and `orWhereNull` method because normal `where` would not work when you are querying null values.

Try something like this (edited after comment):

```
$query = Color::when($itemId, function($q) use ($itemId){
           return $q->where('item_id', $itemId);
         })
         ->when(is_null($itemId), function($q) use ($color){
             return $q->when($color, function($q) use ($color){
                        return $q->where('color', $color);
                     })
                      ->when(is_null($color), function($q) {
                        return $q->whereNull('color');
                     });
         })
         ->paginate();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this but somehow it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I think we need to address what you actually want again. Are you actually trying to do this: if item id is provided, just return that item with its assigned colour. And if a colour is provided without an item id, you want all items belonging to that colour (and sometimes null is treated as a valid colour for absence of colour). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @NewbieCoder edited answer based on that. I think this should give you what you want

Comment: Hi, thank you for this! I have another question, what if I have more column like another 3 to be filter how can I make it can as single filter and also multiple filter as well? Means if user search by one dropdown it will get the result same as if user select two or more dropdown. If I use where() and orWhere() it won't return multiple selection. Feel like when() quite tough for that, is there any other way for that?

Comment: I did post the question on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960407/laravel-search-filtering-cannot-single-filter