# Laravel search filtering cannot single filter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multiple dropdown search filter. I can filter all the column of my table if only I select every dropdown. If I'm only selecting one of them or two, it doesn't return any result. Is there anything to add or did I do it wrongly?

Eloquent

```
$query = Table::when($id, function($q) use ($id){
                return $q->where('id', $id);
            })
            ->when($state, function($q) use ($state){
                return $q->where('state', $state);
            })
            ->when($country, function($q) use ($country){
                return $q->where('country', $country);
            })
            ->when($name, function($q) use ($name){
                return $q->where('name', $name);
            })
            ->when($city, function($q) use ($city){
                return $q->where('city', $city);
            })
            ->when($status, function($q) use ($status){
                return $q->where('status', $status);
            })
        ->paginate(10);

return $query;
```

Controller

```
if ($request->id || $request->state || $request->country|| $request->name || $request->city || $request->name || $request->status){
      $filter = $eloquent->getTable($request->id, $request->state, //all request);
}
else{
     $filter = $eloquent->all();
}
```

Or is there any other way that can be done? Guide and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Couldnt notice anything wrong with the query itself. Sometimes when stuck like this analysing the resulting sql query to see if it actually produces what I want helps me. Sometimes I tend to run that sql in mysql/db admin to see if it actually fetches data. You can use `toSql()` instead of `paginate` to see the query.

Comment: I think when you're saying "If I'm only selecting one of them or two, it doesn't return any result", it means that the one of those 2 fields is "id" (I just assume that). So in that case probably you've filtered "id" and another field as well, which returns nothing. Try to select anything 2 columns except from "id", then you could get something. So I think the problem is that you're filtering "id". Is that make sense ??

Comment: @boolfalse actually the id field is a search field while others are dropdown

Comment: Anyways, try to build your query part by part. Try only with 1 field, then 2, then 3, etc.. With that you can find the issue. (Don't forget sometimes clear the cache)

Comment: @boolfalse just did with the first two when clause. Can filter the second when clause alone and both clause. The first when return nothing.

Comment: when you nest the conditions like that, the second one filters the results of first; so you might want to break down the query in parts and check for conditions

Comment: @archvayu how do I break it? Do I write in the same function? I'm quite new in this, is there any example of break part the query?

Comment: I can answer you an example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = Model::query();

if(isset($id))
 $query->where('id', $id);
if(isset($state))
 $query->where('state', $state);
if(isset($country))
 $query->where('country', $country);
if(isset($name))
 $query->where('name', $name);
if(isset($city))
 $query->where('city', $city);
if(isset($status))
 $query->where('status', $status);
return $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Just try it, it still return the same result. I just update my controller, might be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @NewbieCoder send complete controller. I think that your problem is in your controller

Answer (score 0):

declare your query first then you can climb up the condition tree from the lowest value from your dropdown selections;

```
$query = Table::when($status, function($q) use ($status){
            return $q->where('status', $status);
        });

if(isset($city)) {
    $query = $query->when($city, function($q) use ($city) {
                 return $q->where('city', $city);
             });
}

if(isset($name)) {
    $query = $query->when($name, function($q) use ($name) {
                 return $q->where('name', $name);
             });
}
// climb up the condition tree you want to check from least dependent variable to most dependent variable
...
...
// return filtered results
return $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I got an error ''syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')''' I think there should be a bracket before }; 

I did put the bracket and the error fix but the result still the same.

Comment: what fields are mandatory on your form? you can omit few conditions or even make a new one depending on your needs

Comment: non is mandatory, user can select any filter field. Either all or only one or two

Comment: check the inputs value from the from if they are showing up fine; try with one selection first and move on to the next; there has to ba a way; keep trying

Comment: Try a different approach, seems like it still return the same result. I just edit and add up my controller. Might be the reason why it doesn't work..